# I used SQL sum groupby, why is it a total sum rather than a group-by-group sum?

Tags: sql, sum

example

```
CREATE TABLE book(
    title VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, 
    price INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE buyer(
    name VARCHAR(20) ,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    primary key(name,title),
    foreign key(title)
    references book
)
```

I will omit the code to input data

```
book data = {('a',100),('b',200),('c',100),('d',300)}
buyer data = {('kim','a'),('kim','b'),('ca','c'),('yan','d'),('yan','c')}

select name, sum(price) sum_price
from book,buyer
group by name
```

I want to know the total by name

but this result is the sum of all books.

I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: `book, buyer` is the same as `CROSS JOIN`. Just check the result with `SELECT *` without the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't make a proper join and as a result you ended up with a cross join, which means each row of the `book` table will be joined with each row of the `buyer` table. Try to either add a `where` statement with correct join of the 2 tables, or use `join` syntax in the `from` part.

Comment: cross join, not full outer join.

Comment: yeah you're right @jarlh!

Answer (score 0):

Joining two tables without a join condition produces the full cartesian product of the two tables.

Try this, should solve your problem.

```
select name, sum(price) sum_price
from buyer br left join book bk on br.title=bk.title
group by name
```